# stream audio files to play from google drive using google drive api in android

Tags: android, audio, google-drive-api

I have developed an android app using which one can upload,download,create files on Google Drive.Now I want to play audio files (not after downloading but streaming )which are on Google Drive in custom music player.
For playing audio files I'm using link provided in music file response such as

```
musicFile.getSelfLink()
musicFile.getAlternateLink()
musicFile.getSelfLink()
musicFile.getDefaultOpenWithLink()
musicFile.getWebContentLink()
```

I tried all links provided in response.But could not play music file.It gave me errors like

Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side or media player error

Please help me.Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorize the `file.getDownloadLink()` with your user's access token. You should be able to stream it.

Comment: But,How to authorize url with token ? I have searched on web ,now I have token but how to use that for playing song using mediaplayer from google drive audio url ?

Comment: Got the solution to authorize url.Just pass the token in authorization header .Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

When you need to play your private files, you need next link:

```
String link = file.getDownloadUrl() + "&access_token=" + yourToken + "&alt=media";
```

It works for me in REST API v2

Comment: Is there a solution for Google Drive API V3?